# How to Insert multiple Form Data in CakePHP as new row in database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I use Jquery Clone for adding more form for filling data. then i want to add all data of form individually in a new row of database. database table will be.ex. according my array.

```
name | author | category
 ABC    2         1
 XYZ    2         1
 PQR    5         2
```

my array

```
Array
(
    [Book] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ABC
                    [1] => XYZ
                    [2] => PQR
                )

            [author] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 5
                )

            [category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `$form_data = $this->request->data;
$this->Book->saveMany($form_data);
//$this->Book->saveAll($form_data);`

i thing code needed some looping code. but i don't know.

Comment: Edit your question and put the code you tried there. Then you have a better chance that someone will answer.

Comment: add your view file code here as you are not getting data from form

Comment: `<?php echo $this->Form->create('Book'); ?>
 <div id="parent" align="center"> 
  <div class="inner">
   <?php 
  echo $this->Form->input('Book.name.');
  echo $this->Form->input('Book.author.');
  echo $this->Form->input('Book.category.');
   ?>      
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  <?php
  echo $this->Form->submit('Submit',array('class'=>'btn btn-default','id'=>'send'));
     ?>
 <?php
  echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>`

Comment: edit your question instead of adding as comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to put your data in saveAll compatible format like this

```
array(
'Book' => array(
 0 => array(
  'name' => 'xxx',
  'author' => 'yyy',
 ),
 1 => array(
  'name' => 'aaa',
  'author' => 'bbb',
 )
)
)
```

you can do that by traforming your jquery clone passed data. something like this. Note: not tested

```
$data = array();
$names = Hash::extract($jquerycloneData,'Book.name');//array(ABC,XYZ,PQR);
$authors = Hash::extract($jquerycloneData,'Book.author');
$categories = Hash::extract($jquerycloneData,'Book.category');
$i=0;

for($i, $i<count($names) ,$i++){

   $data['Book'][$i]['name'] = $names[$i]; 
   $data['Book'][$i]['author'] = $authors[$i];
   $data['Book'][$i]['category'] = $categories[$i];
   }
```

then simply call saveAll in your Book model

```
$this->saveAll($data);
```

assuming your data arrived in the format you provided above

Answer (score 3):

Generate the form fields with names like -

```
echo $this->Form->input('Book.0.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Book.1.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Book.0.author');
echo $this->Form->input('Book.1.author');
```

Then You will get the data like -

```
array(
  'Book' => array(
     0 => array(
      'name' => 'xxx',
      'author' => 'yyy',
     ),
     1 => array(
      'name' => 'aaa',
      'author' => 'bbb',
     )
  )
)
```

Then the `saveMany()` will work with them properly.

Comment: i am using Jquery Clone function for adding more forms.


my view file something looks like

`<?php echo $this->Form->create('Book'); ?>
 <div id="parent" align="center"> 
  <div class="inner">
   <?php 
  echo $this->Form->input('Book.name.');
  echo $this->Form->input('Book.author.');
  echo $this->Form->input('Book.category.');
   ?>      
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  <?php
  echo $this->Form->submit('Submit',array('class'=>'btn btn-default','id'=>'send'));
     ?>
 <?php
  echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>`

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->Book->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

or

```
$this->Book->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```